# Static Webpage Loads with Full Functionality from Desktop but Not Online

Tags: javascript, sql, github

My friend was able to replicate this problem where he can grab my code off of github, save it as an .html on his computer, and it is fully functional. However when you use github html preview or amazon s3 to host the static .html and view it online, some of its interactive functionality isn't there. Certain things don't seem to be working including a sql call, javascript to change the cursor behavior, as well as highchart.js. The .html only references external js libraries (cartodb.js, highchart.js), and all the css and javascript is inside the .html file. I've just never heard of a .html file behaving differently if loaded from the desktop vs from online when there are no other local file dependencies. Could it have to do with there being server-side scripting inside the .html?

Comment: What are your setting on your github preview/s3 bucket/files?  I am most familiar with S3, but your settings can make a large difference.

Comment: I think it has to do with having inline actual sql or javascript statements.. rather than just referencing an external API library. cssdeck can preview it with full functionality while jsfiddle and others dont.